# Can't sign in with google in flutter with an error `sign_in_failed`

Tags: flutter

I am using `google_sign_in` (https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) in a flutter app. The code I have is

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);
final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
```

When I launch the app, a google signin dialog is popup and after I type in `email` and `password`. The popup closed and I got an exception:

```
I/flutter ( 5062): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
```

I have signed my apk based on https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

I have searched and found there are some people mention to add this dependency on `build.gradle`.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

I did that but it doesn't solve the issue. Also I see someone says I need to add SHA1 and SHA256 on firebase console. However, my error happens after google sign in and it hasn't come to firebase step yet.

Also I am not going to use `firebase`, instead I am using `cognito` as authentication provider. But I don't think this error relates to `firebase` or `cognito`. It fails at the very beginning of this process. I need to get the `googleSignInAccount` from `googleSignIn.signIn();` response then put the token to other provider.

So how can I fix the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

Level 10 issue is related to dev error i.e there might be some misconfiguration.
Please ensure the following things:

- There is one more thing you need to do in app-level `build.grade` you need to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.
- Make sure your google web API is enabled and the OAuth consent form is filled before you could start using google sign in, which is available in google API console.

  I hope this Helps!

Comment: I have configured cognito user pool with google provider and I am able to authenticate it via browser. Is this process required by android app only?